# Scipy Interpolate LSQUnivariateSpline closed spline tangency

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, spline

I'm wondering how to resolve an issue I have with the Scipy Interpolate module "LSQUnivariateSpline", I'm trying to fit a B-spline through a set of 2D-points. Here the LSQUnivariateSpline method works perfectly, the code returns a set of X/Y points I can use to create a DXF spline.

During some unittesting I discovered a small flaw in my design. For the unittest I created some simple shapes (in X/Y points): an oval shape, a startshape, a square shape and so on...

For the square shape the start and end point are in the corner of the square. If I now plot the b-spline 2D-points, it shows that the start and end points aren't tangent. All other corners show some best-fitting to mitigate the sharp angle.

Does anyone know how to make sure the start/end points are also considered in this best-fit tangency fitting?

Example:
[image: square points]
[image: square points]

Below is the method used to create the X/Y points. It takes a numpy-2D-array as an input.

```
def b_spline_interpolation(np_xy_points: np.array) -> np.array:
    """Creates a b-spline based on the scipy module 'interpolate' and it's method 'LSQ Univariate Spline'."""

    # interpolate based on the 'LSQ Univariate Spline'
    ui = np.cumsum(np.r_[[0], np.linalg.norm(np.diff(np_xy_points, axis=0), axis=1)])
    knots = np.linspace(ui[0], ui[-1], 40)
    try:
        sx = interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline(ui, np_xy_points[:, 0], knots[1:-1], k=3)
        sy = interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline(ui, np_xy_points[:, 1], knots[1:-1], k=3)
    except ValueError as err:
        log.error(f"Failed to create the LSQ Univariate Spline, error: {err}")
        return np.array([])

    # sampling the resulting spline
    uu = np.linspace(ui[0], ui[-1], 150)
    xx = sx(uu)
    yy = sy(uu)

    # create the numpy 2D array
    np_xy_array = np.vstack((xx, yy)).T

    return np_xy_array
```

EDIT 1 - For background reference:
I'm trying to fit a b-spline to a set of unordered points from a point cloud. The point cloud is captured by a laser scanner, and therefore the structure of a 2D slice of the dataset is inherently difficult to manage.
The python library I'm trying to build takes 2D slices of the point cloud and fits b-splines through all points, all this while cleaning up the points, ordering them and trying to get a bare minimum point cloud fit of the b-spline. While building the code base, I needed some simple 2D point sets to test some routines in the code. There I discovered this anti-rounding (which I want to keep).

Best regards,
LVX

Comment: The `LSQUnivariateSpline` does not seem to have a mode for periodic boundary conditions. However you could use [np.pad](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to manually append your data (mode `wrap`). Basically adding the points from the beginning to the end of the array and vice versa.

Comment: You could switch to using [CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline) as it allows bc_type='periodic'. That would let you have a continuously differentiable spline from the transition from the end of the polygon back around to the start. Can you add enough data/code to your question to make it reproducible?

Comment: Hi Nick, surely I can, but could you explain the needs such than I can more narrowly add it. In essence the code takes a csv file, filters the points per 2d plane/layer, after that it sorts them making sure the "np_xy_points" as mentioned above is a clean and ordered array of 2D X/Y (or any other plane) points.

Comment: @Axel, that is exactly what I do, in the code I make sure that the start and end points have the same X/Y coordinates.

Comment: Depending on the order of the spline, connecting the end points is not enough. You need to append more points to both the beginning and end.

Comment: @Axel, Can you clarify how to do this, I mean determine the number of points?Maybe also clarify why this is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Are your data noisy and you need to smooth over the noise? Otherwise there is no reason to use LSQUnivariateSpline (lsq = least squares here).
If you want interpolation indeed, the tool for the job is CubicSpline with bc_type="periodic", as suggested in the comments. Alternatively, `splprep` might be handier for parametric curves; make sure to add `s=0` to force interpolation.

All that said, if the data has sharp corners and you want to preserve them in the curve, you don't want or need cubic splines; they are twice continuously differentiable, thus inevitably round out the corners (and often produce undulations around sharp features). Why not just fit four straight lines instead?

Comment: Indeed ev-br, that would seam as the easy way of doing it, but by your way of answering I noticed the missing info I didn't provide. Therefore I edited the original post and edit the information.